# How can I get the value of a data attribute from my tr element?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<tr data-rk="050500" data-pk="0006000" id="row_2">
```

I am trying to get the value of the data elements like this but it does not work. How can I do it ?  Also how can I get the id for the row and put that into a variable?

```
var data-rk = $(this).('data-rk');
```

Note that the $(this). part already worked when I used it to set CSS. I need to use $(this). as I want to do this for a row when it's clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside using `.attr` method, you could use `.data` method.

```
var data_rk = $(this).data('rk');
```

***Update:***
`.data` method will try do number conversion in your case, so

```
var data_rk = $(this).data('rk'); // will give you number 6000
var data_rk = $(this).attr('data-rk'); // will give you string '0006000'
```

Comment: +1 any `data-*` attribute on the DOM is better accessed this way (with jQuery) since jQuery simulates a `data` object on the DOM and lets you set/get multiple properties at the same time

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. What is the difference? I seem to remember something about one or the other doing some number conversion to string or something like that.

Comment: I read about getting multiple properties at the same time. Actually I also want to get data-pk and put it into a variable. What do you mean when you say "at the same time"?

Comment: That won't quite work. jQuery will convert `0006000` to `6000` when you use `data` so this will fail if the leading zeros are significant: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mvtMz/

Comment: @Anne Yep, as muistooshort pointed, it will do the number conversion for your case.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data_rk = $(this).attr('data-rk')
```

Comment: Sorry but how can I get the id? I must use $(this).

Answer (score 0):

```
   var data-rk =  $("#row_2).attr("data-pk");
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use the `data-` prefix you can get  it like this:

```
var rk = $el.data('rk')
```

Comment: Not really, the data type mangling the jQuery does when using `.data()` can make a mess of things: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mvtMz/