# Adopting variable values from HTML data-atributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

*EDIT

I have a list in my HTML called "#wordlist". In this list I hold the words in my game, the attached audio and the attached image to each word. This all works fine.

Because there will be different versions of the game, I have been asked to take some of the variables capable of changing the amount of words to complete, size of the grid etc; and place them as data-attributes in the list. (Making all the editing factors available in one place).

The problem is I can't get my head around how I am going to type a value in for something like "number-input" below and that changing the variable "numberInput" in the script.

Is this possible to do?

Here is the list (data-word, data-audio and data-pic are all OK)

```
<ul id="wordlist">
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/one.png" data-word="one" data-number-input="" data-completion-number"" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/two.png" data-word="two" data-number-input="" data-completion-number"" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/three.png" data-word="three" data-number-input="" data-completion-number"" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/four.png" data-word="four" data-number-input="" data-completion-number"" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/five.png" data-word="five" data-number-input="" data-completion-number"" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/six.png" data-word="six" data-number-input="" data-completion-number"" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/seven.png" data-word="seven" data-number-input="" data-completion-number"" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/eight.png" data-word="eight" data-number-input="" data-completion-number"" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/nine.png" data-word="nine" data-number-input="" data-completion-number"" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/ten.png" data-word="ten" data-number-input="" data-completion-number"" data-grid=""></li>
</ul>
```

Here are the variable that I need to change through the data-attributes in the HTML

```
var numberInput = 2;
var completionNumber = 2;
var smallGrid = {
    x: 4,
    y: 4
};
var largeGrid = {
    x: 8,
    y: 6
};
```

So basically So if `"data-number-input="2"` this would make the variable `"numberInput = 2;"` in the script

Comment: `number-input`, `completion-number` and `grid` are not [data attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#custom-data-attribute).

Comment: You need to change those attributes to data attributes.

Comment: What exactly are you asking. Are you asking how to get the data attribute value from the element? If so, what event should cause this to happen?

Comment: You can use .data() to retrieve the values from those attributes now. To set values you would use attr().

Comment: I am trying to change the variable in the scripts value through the corresponding data-attributes value. So if the "data-number-input="2"" this would make the variable "numberInput = 2;"

Comment: @Milo-J: Right, but where are you stuck? We already know that you understand how to assign a value to a variable. So is it that you don't know how to set up an event handler? Or you don't know how to retrieve the value?

Comment: I don't know how to retrieve the value from the data-attribute @user1689607

Comment: Alright, in that case, did you search for the answer first? [How can I get the value of a data attribute from my tr element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606258/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-data-attribute-from-my-tr-element)

Comment: -1 You guys are completely confused and asked for something that it's not clear but ok I can live with that, but then don't know what exactly need when already got an answer with lot of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `html` wasn't good at all, you must change it to this:

*(`data` attributes were corrected...)*

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="wordlist">
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/one.png" data-word="one" data-number-input="" data-completion-number="" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/two.png" data-word="two" data-number-input="" data-completion-number="" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/three.png" data-word="three" data-number-input="" data-completion-number="" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/four.png" data-word="four" data-number-input="" data-completion-number="" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/five.png" data-word="five" data-number-input="" data-completion-number="" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/six.png" data-word="six" data-number-input="" data-completion-number="" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/seven.png" data-word="seven" data-number-input="" data-completion-number="" data-grid=""></li>
        <li data-audio="" data-pic="images/eight.png" data-word="eight" data-number-input="" data-completion-number="" data-grid=""></li>
</ul>​
```

Then, to assign new values to the `data` attributes, use the following. In this case I just affected the first `li` but you can do a `loop` or `.map()` in jQuery if you want to change all of them.

**Live DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/qWyj6/1/

**jQuery code:**

```
var numberInput = 2;
var completionNumber = 2;
var smallGrid = {
    x: 4,
    y: 4
};

//In this case, this is just affecting the first 'li' inside 'ul' that's why '.eq(0)' is used.
elem = $('ul#wordlist li').eq(0);
elem.data('number-input', numberInput.toString());
elem.data('completion-number', completionNumber.toString());
elem.data('grid', smallGrid.x + ',' + smallGrid.y);

//Print new 'data' attributes in console to look they've changed.
console.log(elem.data('number-input'));
console.log(elem.data('completion-number'));
console.log(elem.data('grid'));
```

---

**Changing all `li` attributes:**

just do this using jQuery, this is like the "equivalent" of a `loop`:

**Live DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/qWyj6/2/

*(In live demo check browser's console to see the output)*

```
$('ul#wordlist li').map(function(i, v) {
    $(this).data('number-input', numberInput.toString());
    $(this).data('completion-number', completionNumber.toString());
    $(this).data('grid', smallGrid.x + ',' + smallGrid.y);
});​
```

---

**If you want to get the `data` attribute from a `li` and put in a variable, just do this:**

```
//Getting 'number-input' attribute from the first 'li':
var numberInput = $('ul#wordlist li').eq(0).data('number-input');
```

---

**But, If you want to get all `data` attributes from all `li` and put them in variables or javascript `object`, just do this:**

```
var data = $('ul#wordlist li').map(function(i, v) {

    var numberInput = $(this).data('number-input');
    var completionNumber = $(this).data('completion-number');
    var gridX = $(this).data('grid').split(',')[0];
    var gridY = $(this).data('grid').split(',')[1];

    return {
        numberInput: numberInput,
        completionNumber: completionNumber,
        grid: {
            x: gridX,
            y: gridY
        }
    };
}).get();
```

**Live DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/qWyj6/3/

This will be the output:

[image]

And, to get for example the `number-input` value from the first `li` of this `object`, just do this:

```
console.log(data[0].numberInput);
```

---

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Does this allow me to change through the HTML? @Oscar Jara

Comment: @Milo-J Yes, `jQuery` modifies your `DOM` without problems but you won't be able to see this when maybe doing right click and look your `html` source-code but it's modified in `DOM`.

Comment: So if I changed "data-number-input" to 1, then "numberInput" would change to 1 as well? @Oscar Jara

Comment: @Milo-J No, you need to specify as my example what's the new value for each `data` attribute.

Comment: @Milo-J check my update if you want to change all `li` attributes values.

Comment: You'd need to track which of your LIs stored the value you've assigned. Is there a reason you have number-inputs in every LI when you (seem to be asking) for just one value? @Oscar Jara

Comment: So I would have to create a separate part for data-number-input, data-completion-number and data-grid and assign it as a whole. Is that what you mean? @AMD

Comment: Hey, you cannot assign automatically the values you want in the right place without specifying, check the updated part of my post, if you want to change all `li` data just do that @Milo-J

Comment: It really depends on your requirements, which aren't fully clear to me. Do you need every LI to have its own number-inputs value, for example, or just one to be read once on the page

Comment: @AMD it seems this is not clear at all for me, what you want to achieve? change just one li data attribute? change all data attributes of one li? or change all data attributes of all li? In the first and second case, you can follow my first example (if you just want to change the number-input, there is no reason to assign the other values). For third case just follow the last part from my post, I really don't understand what is not clear.

Comment: Apologies, my comment that began 'You'd need to track which of your LIs...' should have been a reply to the original poster. I think we are in agreement Oscar Jara

Comment: Sorry I know I have been a bit unclear, as I am unclear myself as to how I want to achieve it. Looking at it now I would only need data-number-input, data-completion-number and data-grid to be changed once in order to apply it to the script. So is there a way to do that? @AMD

Comment: Well, the code is for changing the attributes you need, I think it's clear. @Milo-J

Comment: I would add those attributes to the UL then, and read them once. Use .data or adapt one of the getAttribute examples to retrieve this.

Comment: would I but them in an <li> do you think? @AMD

Comment: would it be something along these lines? numberInput.push({
            "input": elm.data("number-input"),
        });

Comment: Sorry, no ofense but you guys really need to make some research instead of asking and doing things that you really don't have any idea of what you exactly need. Everything is in my post, I also included more information now, have to go @Milo-J

Answer (score 1):

Untested example, get each instance of **data-**number-input and push it into an array:

```
    var numberInputs = [];  
    var list = document.getElementByID('wordlist');
    var listItems = list.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(var i = 0;i<listItems.length;i++) {
      numberInputs.push = listItems[i].getAttribute('data-number-input');
    }
```

Comment: I like this answer. The problem is once I retrieve the value from the data-attribute, how would I put it into the variable @AMD

Comment: You could read a single LI using listItems[3].getAttribute('data-number-input') for example. It depends which of all of them you want to use. I assumed you wanted them all so put them in an array