# pusing HTML attributes into arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adopting variable values from HTML data-atributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253556/adopting-variable-values-from-html-data-atributes)

How do I get the attributes in this

```
<li data-number-input="2" data-completion-number="2"></li>
```

To push into these arrays

```
var numberInput = [];
var completionNumber = [];
```

I have tried this but it crashes my program

```
 numberInput.push({
        "input": elm.data("number-input")
    });
 completionNumber.push({
        "completion": elm.data("completion-number")
    });
```

This is an extension of a previous question... [Adopting variable values from HTML data-atributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253556/adopting-variable-values-from-html-data-atributes)

Comment: Why does this _crash_ ? Do you get a error message? If so, what is the error message.

Comment: Why did you change user accounts to ask this? With all due respect, I think [Oscar Jara's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253556/adopting-variable-values-from-html-data-atributes#comment18062244_13253862) under his answer is right. You seem to be asking about things without really understanding any of it. Seems like you need to learn some basics first.

Comment: ...also, you posted this question earlier *(but after your original one)*, but then deleted it when people started asking you the same sort of questions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var numberInput = [];
var completionNumber = [];

$('li[data-number-input],li[data-completion-number]').each(function(){
   numberInput.push($(this).attr('data-number-input'));
   completionNumber.push($(this).attr('data-completion-number'));
});
```

this will iterate over all `li`'s that have the attributes `data-number-input` and `data-completion-number` and for each one of those, it will push the respective value to these arrays.

Comment: That looks good to me +1

Comment: You don't want the `,li` part of the selector if what you're looking for is `li` elements with both attributes.

Comment: Well i didn't know what was OP's intention about those parameters. he might have elements with only one of those properties. (in which case, an if around each of these pushes is in order).

Comment: Could you show me what you mean @Rodik